# Safely handling potentially malicious URLs using Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, phishing

I'm building a tool for analyzing emails to try to determine if they're phishing or not and I'd like to see if any of the links in the email redirect, and if they do how many times and to where. I'm currently using the requests library to handle all of that stuff and in order to get a link's history you have to call .get(). Is this safe to do on potentially malicious URLs, and if not is there any way I can get the redirect information without putting my computer at risk?

Comment: By "malicious URL", do you mean a URL that points to a page with malicious content, a URL that attempts to perform CSRF, or something else?

Comment: Any of the above? I'm not really sure what a lot of the malicious links are trying to do. Most of them are just malicious content, but I can't say for certain there aren't CSRF attacks or things like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send a HEAD request with `allow_redirects=True`:

```
>>> url = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/57298432/7954504"
>>> resp = requests.request(
...     "HEAD",
...     url,
...     allow_redirects=True
... )
>>> resp.history
[<Response [301]>, <Response [302]>]
>>> [i.url for i in resp.history]
['http://stackoverflow.com/q/57298432/7954504', 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/57298432/7954504']
```

Not saying this is a cure-all.  Something else to consider is adding some heuristics on the URL itself, in the spirit of "you know a crappy-looking URL when you see one."  (I like [`yarl`](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/) for analyzing URLs.)  For instance:

- What's the file extension?
- Is the URl using a nonstandard port?
- Is the domain an IPv4/6 address or localhost?
- Are any of the query parameter values themselves valid URLs?

...and so on.

Comment: How does the list comprehension statement you've made know what to be looping over? I'm not familiar with using the underscore the way that you've done it here. BTW for anyone who's not familiar with this syntax, you can just do:
`[r.url for r in resp.history]`

Comment: In the shell, `_` is a shorthand for the last result @ChrisCombs